# Add PivotTable to Open Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have done a fair amount of research on how to add a pivot table to another workbook but am coming up short.

**My Data Set**

Macro is stored in `ThisWorkbook`

Source Data for PivotTable is stored in the *Open Workbook - Sheet name "Raw Data"*

Destination of PivotTable wanted on the same *Open Workbook* but on *Sheet name "Claim Summary"*

**Caveat**

This `procedure` is pat of a much wider project. As such I have a few `module declarations`:

`Private wbReconcile As Workbook`

`Private wsRawData As Worksheet`

`Private wsSummary As Worksheet`

These are then set in a differnet procedure (within the same module) as such:

`Set wbReconcile = Workbooks.Open(RECON_FILE, False)`

`Set wsRawData = wbReconcile.Sheets("Raw Data")`

`Set wsSummary = wbReconcile.Sheets("Claim Summary")`

**Problem & Error**

The problem I have is that no matter if I use my `variables` or type out the name of the workbook, name of the worksheet/s etc.. I always get an error on the line `Set myPivotTable` Error Message: Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument.

**My Code**

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()

    Dim myDestinationWorkbook As Workbook
    Set myDestinationWorkbook = Workbooks("Template_Promo Claims Reconciliation.xlsm")
'    Set myDestinationWorkbook = wbReconcile

    Dim mySourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set mySourceWorksheet = myDestinationWorkbook.Worksheets("Raw Data")
'    Set mySourceWorksheet = wsRawData
    Dim myDestinationWorksheet As Worksheet
    Set myDestinationWorksheet = myDestinationWorkbook.Worksheets("Claim Summary")
'    Set myDestinationWorksheet = wsSummary

    'obtain address of destination cell range
    Dim myDestinationRange As String
    myDestinationRange = myDestinationWorksheet.Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

    Dim mySourceData As String
    mySourceData = mySourceWorksheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

    'create Pivot Table cache and create Pivot Table report based on that cache
    Dim myPivotCache As PivotCache
    Set myPivotCache = _
        myDestinationWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
        SourceData:="[" & myDestinationWorkbook.name & "]" & _
        mySourceWorksheet.name & "!" & _
        mySourceData)

    Dim myPivotTable As PivotTable
    Set myPivotTable = myPivotCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="[" & _
        myDestinationWorkbook.name & "]" & myDestinationWorksheet.name & "!" & _
        myDestinationRange, TableName:="RawDataPivot")

End Sub
```

**EDIT TO SHOW HOW ANSWER IS USED**

```
Sub AnswerPT()

    Dim pc As PivotCache, pt As PivotTable
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range

    Set wsSrc = wsRawData
    Set wsDest = wsSummary   'for convenience here

    Set rngSrc = wsSrc.Range("A1").CurrentRegion  'source data
    Set rngDest = wsDest.Range("A1")    'table location

    Set pc = wsDest.Parent.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                            SourceData:=rngSrc, Version:=6)

    Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=rngDest, _
                          TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=6)

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: updated post: Error Message: Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument.

Comment: If `myDestinationWorksheet.Name` contains spaces the sheet name needs to be in single quotes.  No harm in *always* adding single quotes in this type of case.

Comment: @TimWilliams how? im lost as I have tried double quotes and all sorts.. can you please provide an example.

Comment: Have you tried just using `TableDestination := myDestinationWorksheet.Range("A1")` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams worked! put that in an answer and i will tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ranges directly without constructing the "stringified" version of them:

```
Dim pc As PivotCache, pt As PivotTable
Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range

Set wsSrc = ActiveSheet
Set wsDest = ActiveSheet   'for convenience here

Set rngSrc = wsSrc.Range("C5:E14")  'source data
Set rngDest = wsDest.Range("I5")    'table location

Set pc = wsDest.Parent.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                        SourceData:=rngSrc, Version:=6)

Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=rngDest, _
                      TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=6)
```

Comment: ...although the docs do recommend using a string for `SourceData` in `PivotCaches.Create`. Or is that fixed depending on the version of Excel?

Comment: can confirm the above works. I thought also needed a `string` as per MS Docs.. But alas the above is so neat and succinct

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcache.createpivottable here `TableDestination` is a Variant and the example code uses a `Range` object as the argument.

Comment: From [`PivotCaches.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create): "When passing a Range object, we recommend that you either use a string to specify the workbook, worksheet, and cell range, or set up a named range and pass the name as a string. Passing a Range object may cause "type mismatch" errors unexpectedly." I'm wondering if this is still an issue? Definitely answered one or two questions with that error.